# Unable to find Contact by Number due to Formatting difference

Tags: android, android-contacts

It's supposed to be a common problem but I don't know what is the right word to look for solution.

In my app, I user can key in a number, and I need to search if the contact exist in database. Also, given a contact ID and number, I want to find the phone label of the number..

The problem is, if I have a number in phone as "8710 2863" and my query arg is "87102863", I won't be able to get the contact and phone label... There must be a way to standardize the format.. But I can't find the way :(

Here is my code:

```
Cursor cursor = MyApp.getContext().getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL
                },
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND "
                        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ? ",
                new String[] { Long.toString(contactId), number },
                ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY + " DESC");

        if (cursor != null) {
            try {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int type = cursor.getInt(0);
                    String label = cursor.getString(1);
                    String phoneLabel = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
                            .getTypeLabel(MyApp.getContext().getResources(), type, label);
                    hashBuilder.put(Defs.ARG_PHONE_TYPE, phoneLabel);
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried [`PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNumber%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: @Barend that's magic. I use PhoneNUmberUtil.format it doesn't work as well as PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(). Please leave your answer and i will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [`PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNumber%28java.lang.String%29)?